# Add a multi index column to a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I made a data frame which has a similar structure to the following df

```
#                          val_1  val_2
# level_1 level_2 level_3              
# A0      B0      C0          98     90
#                 C1          44      9
#         B1      C2          39     17
#                 C3          75     71
# A1      B2      C0           1     89
#                 C1          54     60
#         B3      C2          47      6
#                 C3          16      5
# A2      B0      C0          75     22
#                 C1          19      4
#         B1      C2          25     52
#                 C3          57     40
# A3      B2      C0          64     54
#                 C1          27     96
#         B3      C2         100     77
#                 C3          22     50
```

I want to add a column to the right of `level_1` whose value is the sum of `val_1` for each sub df of A. So `98 + 44 + 39 + 75` is added beside `A0` and so on.

Comment: IIUC, `df.sum(level=0)`?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) to new column with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(level=0)['val_1'].transform('sum')
df = df.set_index('new', append=True).reorder_levels([0,3,1,2])

print (df)
                             val_1  val_2
level_1 new level_2 level_3              
A0      256 B0      C0          98     90
                    C1          44      9
            B1      C2          39     17
                    C3          75     71
A1      118 B2      C0           1     89
                    C1          54     60
            B3      C2          47      6
                    C3          16      5
A2      176 B0      C0          75     22
                    C1          19      4
            B1      C2          25     52
                    C3          57     40
A3      213 B2      C0          64     54
                    C1          27     96
            B3      C2         100     77
            B2      C3          22     50
```